# How to REMOVE lower case tokens with R?

Tags: r, quanteda

I'm using R/Quanteda and I'm trying to make a wordcloud from ONLY upper case words. The txt is a from a bibliographic reference in ABNT format, doing so I would keep only the authors surnames.
Any hint? Tanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to S.O! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already. This question would be greatly helped by a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is generally what we expect on this site. Learn more about how to make these with R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-exampl).

Answer (score 1):

### Base R

```r
string <- "lowercase UPPERCASE more lower case UPPER  1143 + 40 = !!!"

gsub(" {2,}", " ", # replace 2 or more consecutive spaces with one space
  gsub("[^A-Z ]", "", string) # remove anything that's not a space or an uppercase letter
)
#> [1] " UPPERCASE UPPER "
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### Stringr Package

```r
require(stringr)
#> Loading required package: stringr

string <- "lowercase UPPERCASE more lower case UPPER  1143 + 40 = !!!"

str_squish( # remove excess whitespace
  str_remove_all(string, "[^[:UPPER:] ]") #remove everything except uppecase and spaces
)
#> [1] "UPPERCASE UPPER"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>